# If I Implement The iOS 5 Twitter Framework Does my App Contain Encryption?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know if I use the Twitter Framework will my app contain encryption?

Comment: You only need to fill out the [encryption export forms](http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/guidance.htm) if what you're distributing includes encryption. If you're simply linking against operating-system provided encryption routines, you do not need to file for export allowance.

Answer (score 2):

Frameworks are not included in your app.  They are in the device's firmware and are not copied into your app.  So even if an iOS framework had encryption in it, it is not included in your app, you just make function or method calls to it, and are not distributing encryption software.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to be sure because of those "severe penalties".

Answer (score 0):

I think no one really answered your question directly; they were merely inferring your intent. The Twitter framework docs only mention HTTP for API requests. The Twitter [docs on this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/security/using-ssl) say that SSL is optional though encouraged. So I'd imagine that iOS is handling user authentication via SSL in the background, but that all API requests by developers are done over HTTP using oauth. This is only speculation -- to verify you'd want to run a packet sniffer on your local network and check out the transactions when you call the framework methods.

Regarding the export controls mentioned in other comments here, I'd advise you to look at the iTunes Connect FAQ dealing with export controls within the Dev Center. Apple makes it very clear in that document that using encryption integrated into the iOS frameworks still requires you to apply for an ERN with the US Dept. of Commerce. (I won't quote it due to NDA) The other comments currently on this page are simply wishful thinking.  I'm sure some developers were confused (and it is confusing), or perhaps have outright lied and have apps in the store which are violating US law. IANAL; I'll leave that choice up to you.

Having said that, there have been some exemptions added to these requirements, as outlined [here](http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/question2.htm).